# shareAsync error and promise not resolving

Tags: facebook-instant-games

When i call shareAsync function, in chrome console gives next errors:

> POST https://www.facebook.com/react_composer/logging/ods/?event=bootload_start&attachment_type=MEDIA&dpr=1 404 ()
>
> ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Async request failed with error %s: %s when requesting %s","404","Про...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
>
> POST https://www.facebook.com/react_composer/logging/ods/?event=bootstrap_start&attachment_type=MEDIA&dpr=1 404 ()

In network tab, there is really 404 status code.

Also, shareAsync not resolve own promise, but share is works and publish fine in profile page.

This problem has appeared today, yesterday it was not.

Comment: Which surface is this on (e.g. messenger.com, facebook.com, app center, etc)?

Comment: Facebook.com - in chrome console I can watch error. But in iOS facebook app, I can't watch error, but promise returned by shareAsync not resolving.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you;'re using to call the method here? It might be that there's something wrong with the Base64 encoded image.